# Best practice for managing new releases and custom changes to Virtocommerce

Tags: virtocommerce

I am new to VirtoCommerce and I am seeing that version2 is beeing developed right now.
If I want to jump in and make custom changes to my repo.., how can still hold up do date the base with the progress that is made from the community?
Do I need to merge the changes back to my local repo on each version?

i ve seen we can build "modules" is this meant for such a scenario too or only for the marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of refactoring made in the past couple of weeks to VC 2.0 branch. We don't expect such big changes to be made in the future.
Also we are planning to merge all changes to the main branch and use dev branch for ongoing development with releases published to that main branch approximately every 3 weeks (we operate in 3 weeks sprints internally). You can then merge changes from that main branch. Or you can still merge from dev if you want to get updates faster.

Modules are meant for implementing any custom functionality and not only for AppStore (Marketplace). You don't really need to package them if you don't plan to distribute your modules.